# Why isn't it working T extends Record<symbol,unknown>

Tags: typescript

```
type Test<T extends Record<symbol, unknown>> = T;

type Result = Test<{
  a: string;
}>;
```

I made this `T extends Record<symbol, unknown>` , Test only accept index type with symbol key,why Test<{a:string}> no false alarms ?

Comment: If you're asking why `{a: string}` is assignable to `Record<symbol, unknown>` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m359yw), it's because structural typing does not prohibit excess properties (so it's not true that `Test` *only* accepts symbol keys) and `{a: string}` is given an [implicit index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures).  I can explain those in more detail, but I'm not 100% sure if I understood your question correctly.  Can you clarify? (I don't think "false alarm" means what you think it means)

Comment: That's exactly what I want to ask you. My English is not very good. Thank you very much for your help. Have a nice life

Answer (score 0):

Typescript interfaces are "open", meaning that additional properties can be present on an object outside of its known interface, and this is not a compile time error.

For this reason, a value of type `{a: string}` is a valid value for `Record<symbol, unknown>`.

You can verify this with the following code that compiles perfectly fine:

```
const obj: {a: string} = {a: "foo"};
const record: Record<symbol, unknown> = obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be invalid you can intersect it with another Record whose values are `never`:

```
type Test<T extends Record<symbol, unknown> & Record<string | number, never>> = T;;

type Result = Test<{ // ! error, string/number keys should be type never
  a: string;
}>;
```

Works well enough

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwA8MoQB7AgOwCbygCUIBjAewCdcl4QBbAIzIBsAaKAV2wGtsyB3bAD4oAMiKlK1RBQCW2AOZQAPlGwdGECu2wQAblqEiAvLADcZgLAAoG6EgT4HZsCim4iJAG8bUKAEMALigZeQUrawBfITMgA)